# UseEffect is not running cleanup on-dismount

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I have a MessageInput component which triggers a socket connection to the backend when it mounts, and should disconnect from that socket manually on dismount. I am not sure what happened, but at some point yesterday useEffect simply stopped running cleanup.

When I close the app I see the accumulated disconnections all at once.

```sh
User disconnected...
User disconnected...
User disconnected...
```

Is there something I am missing in useEffect?

Here is my code:

```js
useEffect(async () => {
    const accessToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("access-token");
    const socket = socketClient(`${process.env.REACT_APP_backend_url}/`, {
      auth: {
        authToken: accessToken,
      },
    });
    socket.emit("message", message);
    return () => socket.disconnect();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`async` functions return promises, so you're not actually returning a cleanup function. React ignores the promise that you return to it.

You'll need to do something like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
  let socket;
  (async () => {
    const accessToken = await SecureStore.getItemAsync("access-token");
    socket = socketClient(`${process.env.REACT_APP_backend_url}/`, {
      auth: {
        authToken: accessToken,
      },
    });
    socket.emit("message", message);
  })()

  return () => {
    if (socket) {
      socket.disconnect();
    }
  }
}, []);
```

Comment: Thanks it works. Can you pls explain a bit why your way works, as opposed to how I did it? They're both async.

Comment: Because your effect function body has an `await`, it returns a promise. Because React has to continue rendering, it doesn't bother waiting for the resolution and finally getting to the cleanup function. This answer wraps the await in another function so that the effect doesn't return a promise and React actually gets to the cleanup function synchronously.

Comment: Got it now. Thanks.

Comment: I didn't actually know this, I always thought cleanup functions were just flakey.